# R plot heatmap of matrix with superposed line

Tags: r

I have a matrix whose values I want to plot. Using the `image` function it looks like this.

[image: m]

How can I plot a line over the image?
(In my case, it want to plot a line over the maximum values along the `x` axes)

**Edit**

The image and the line I want to plot over are the output from the [Bayesian Online Changepoint detection](http://hips.seas.harvard.edu/content/bayesian-online-changepoint-detection). Since it is quite short I'll share the whole code. The plotting part is at the end:

```
# Bayesian Online Changepoint Detection
# Adams, MacKay 2007
# http://hips.seas.harvard.edu/content/bayesian-online-changepoint-detection
#######################################

# Other python and matlab implementations
# https://github.com/JackKelly/bayesianchangepoint
# http://hips.seas.harvard.edu/content/bayesian-online-changepoint-detection
# http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/rpa23/cp/gaussdemo.m
# http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/rpa23/cp/studentpdf.m
# http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/rpa23/cp/constant_hazard.m

# Even more commented, but different paper:
# https://github.com/davyfeng/ipdata/blob/master/csv/bocpd/core/bocpd.m

# Generate data
x1 <- rnorm(100, 10.5, 0.1)
x2 <- rnorm(100, 1, 0.1)
x3 <- rnorm(100, -10, 0.1)
x4 <- rnorm(100, -1, 0.1)
x5 <- rnorm(100, 5, 0.1)
x6 <- rnorm(30, 1, 0.1)
x7 <- rnorm(100, 8, 0.1)

x <- c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5, x6,x7)

##############
# Algorithm
##############

# Prepare the scaled and shifted student-t 
dt.scaled.shifted <- function(x, m, s, df) stats::dt((x-m)/s, df)/s

# Prepare the Hazard function
hazard <-function(x, lambda=200){rep(1/lambda, length(x))}

L <- length(x)
R <- matrix(rep(0,(L+1)*(L+1)), L+1, L+1)
R[1,1] <- 1 # for t=1 where are sure that p(r=1)=1
mu0 <- 0; kappa0 <- 1; alpha0 <-1; beta0 <- 1;
muT <- mu0
kappaT <- kappa0
alphaT <- alpha0
betaT <- beta0

maxes <- rep(0, L)

# Process data as they come in
for(t in 1:L){
  # Evaluate predictive probability
  predprobs <- dt.scaled.shifted(x[t], muT, betaT*(kappaT+1)/(alphaT*-kappaT), 2*alphaT)

  H <- hazard(x[1:t])

  # Calculate growth probabilities
  R[2:(t+1), t+1] <- R[1:t,t]*predprobs*(1-H)

  # Calculate changepoint (reset) probabilities
  R[1,t+1] <- sum(R[1:t,t]*predprobs*H)

  # Renormalize
  R[,t+1] <- R[,t+1] / sum(R[,t+1])

  # Update parameters for each possible run length
  # keep the past ones since they will be used iteratively
  muT0 <- c(mu0, (kappaT*muT + x[t])/(kappaT+1))
  kappaT0 <- c(kappa0,kappaT+1)
  alphaT0 <- c(alpha0, alphaT + 0.5)
  betaT0 <- c(beta0, kappaT + (kappaT * (x[t]-muT)^2)/(2*(kappaT+1)))
  muT <-  muT0
  kappaT <- kappaT0
  alphaT <- alphaT0
  betaT <- betaT0

  # Store the maximum, to plot later
  maxes[t] <- which.max(R[,t])
}

# Plot results
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(x, type='l')
image((-t(log(R))),  col = grey(seq(0,1,length=256)), axes=T)
par(new=T)
plot(1:(dim(R)[1]-1), maxes,type='l', col="red")
```

[image]

On the top there is the original data. On the bottom, the probability of a current run to have length `y`. **The red line on the bottom should fit the dark shades.**

Comment: You need `x` and `y` values for `lines()`. What is your intention in just passing a single vector? Did you mean `lines(seq(0,1, length=50),seq(0,1, length=50),col="red", lwd=5)`?

Comment: I have a previously computed vector `maxes` with a value for every `x`. `maxes[i] <- which.max(m[,i])`

Comment: @MrFlick my answer does not actually work for my real problem, I'll delete it. I edited the question to reproduce the data.

Answer (score 0):

(to be deleted. It does not work. I leave it temporaly to save the comments.)

I got it, I thought I had already tried `par(new=T)` but obviously I hadn't:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(100,1,1),50,50)
image(m, col = grey(seq(0,1,length=256)))
par(new=T)
plot(seq(0,1, length=50), type='l', col="red", lwd=5)
```

Quick example simulating the whole process:

```
data <- vector()
for(i in 1:50){
  data <- rbind(data, dpois(1:50, i^1.2))
}
maxes <- apply(data, 1, which.max)
image(-data,  col = grey(seq(0,1,length=256)))
par(new=T)
plot(1:dim(data)[1], c(maxes),type='l')
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this completely changes your `x`scale. The is likely not the solution you really want if you want to match up `x` and `y` values with the original plot.

Comment: Yes! I just saw it and thought there was a problem with my data. All yours then :)

Comment: Image rescales everything to 0-1. I'm still not sure why you aren't passing both `x` and `y` values to `lines()`. If you just pass a single vector, it assumes those are `y` values are uses 1,2,3,etc for `x` values. In this case, those `x` values are outside the range of 0-1 so nothing is shown.

Comment: I still think using `par(new=T)` is a bad idea. I'd use `lines(seq(0,1,length.out=length(maxes)), maxes, type="l")`. This example is better than the one you included in the original question. It would have been more helpful to start with this.